# EAAccessoryManager showBluetoothAccessoryPicker localization

Tags: ios, localization, eaaccessory

I am using `showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter` to display a list of bluetooth devices. However, the *title* and *cancel* button of the `alert` list are not localized.

Is there a way to localize those strings from system `alert`? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Change "Localization native development region" in info.plist to your localization instead of en.

[image]